Apache Guacamole image banding
Connect to Windows via RDP with Apache Guacamole. When looking at the graded image (attached below), the banding in the image is noticeable.
What can I do to improve this? Any ideas are welcome.
The apache guacamole server version is 1.5.3.
enter image description here
I changed the values of the display settings but nothing happened.
enter image description here
I tried changing below value
config.method = 2 in src/libguac/encode-webp.c  to
config.method = 6
,but again nothing happened.
